# Setting UIImage in TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code but there is an error when setting the image for the UIImageView:

`[UITableViewCellContentView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e87eb0'`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Get image for the row
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    NSURL *photoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.com/someimage.jpg"];
    UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoURL]];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    imageView.image = photo;
    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Read the error, your `imageView` is not actually a `UIImageView` as you expect it to be.

Comment: It looks like you tagged the cell's content view instead of the image view.

Comment: use outlets, not tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to send the message `setImage` to `UITableViewCellContentView` which is simply a `UIView` and does not have an image property.  It looks like you tagged the wrong portion of your cell. Go back to your XIB or Storyboard and make sure you've tagged a `UIImageView` with 100.

Comment: Yes the UIImageView is tagged with 100.

Comment: Are these prototype cells? Or....What type of cells are you using. You should avoid using tags for this reason.

Comment: Actually this was the answer - I had tagged both my Content and my ImageView as 100.